# Using not Exists on access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am a wholesaler

I have tables

```
customers -> customer_id , companyname , contact_name , phone_number , email , adress and city 

products -> product_id , product_name , unit_price 

Sale -> sale_id , Date , customer_info , Serial_Number ** customer info is customer id

Sales_detail -> Sale_detail_id , Product_ID , Quantity , sale_id
```

and here is my question:

I need to find the products that have not been sold to the customers

for example:

I have p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 and c1 c2 c3

c1 buys p1 p2 so I need a query to find this:  c1 ->> p3 p4 p5

Comment: What have you done so far in order to solve the mentioned issue?

Comment: select customer.contact_name, product.product_name from Sale 
inner join sale_detail on Sale.sale_id = sale_detail.sale_id
inner join customer on customer.customer_id = sale_detail.customer_info
inner join product on product.product_id = sale_detail.ProductID i write something like that ( it has some typos etc. when i come home i corrected all typos ) . I wrote it while on the bus but it didnt work

Comment: that one for getting for the sales , this one for my question select customer.contact_name, product.product_name from product, customer
where not exist(select * from Sale 
        inner join sale_detail on Sale.sale_id = sale_detail.sale_id
        where sale.customer_info = customer.customer_id and sale_detail.ProductID = product.product_id)  and yes this one has typos too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, p.product_id
FROM customers c, products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM sale s
 INNER JOIN sales_detail sd ON s.sale_id = sd.sale_id
 WHERE s.customer_info = c.customer_id
 AND sd.product_id = p.product_id)
 ORDER BY c.customer_id, p.product_id
```

For each customer id, select the product ids where there is not a sale such that the customer info associated with the sale matches the customer id and product associated with the sale matches the product id.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot , it works +,+ ,  what does " select 1 " mean ? by the way

Comment: It’s just a placeholder. The convention is to use 1 but you could put anything there. The point is that nothing is returned in the query.

Comment: Thx man :) best regards